# Javascript Multi Object Array Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

im having a problem with some code that i have. I have the following object (bookingDetails) that has a 'type' property that is an array, which stores objects, which in turn has another array of objects. for example:

```
bookingDetails (object)
- type(array)
    - id
    - share (array)
        Number (object)
```

First off is there a better way to do this? (i need to be able to store numerous 'Numbers' against the share per type)

Secondly if someone clicks a big old 'X' then i need to delete the number from the correct share and, if the share is empty delete the entire type object that the share belonged to.

at the moment i was trying to do this with the following:

```
for(var d in bookingDetails[data[6]]){
    var it = bookingDetails[data[6]][d];
    if(it.ID === data[0]){
        for(var s in it.Sharing){
            var pa = it.Sharing[s];
            for(var p in pa){
                var pax = pa[p];
                for(var pd in paxData){
                    if(pax.PaxNo === paxData[pd]){
                        //what to do here??
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i had a look at splice to remove the objects from the share array but this would then change the array indexes which i a problem for the above loops... it all just seems messy.

Any help would be vastly appreciated as i have been trying to do this for a while now..

If this is not the best method of doing this I would love to know of a better way :)

Thanks

Comment: Beware of using for...in, IE will put attributes like "length" in d.

Comment: thanks - this application will only run in chrome so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk the array backwards if you plan on modifying it as you go.

```
 var i;
 for( i = myarray.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    // ...something that might remove myarray[i]...
 }
```

Can't really speak to your data complexity problem; you may just be trying to represent complex data.  It also may be that you should be using objects with named attributes rather than arrays with unnamed indices.  Either way, for sanity, I would suggest writing utility functions or even an object decorator to isolate the complexity from other parts of your code.

Comment: thanks will give this a try :), would you mind expanding on the "object decorator to isolate complexity"?

Comment: here's a link, but mostly I just mean put some objects around your data with simpler methods.  Abstraction should help you from getting in the weeds deep in the tree when you're working higher up.  Even simpler than that, maybe just write a function which does the manipulation on the object once you've found it, so you rloop logic and iteration can be separate. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
Bookingdetails.types =array with id on the types this bookingdetail belongs to
Bookingdetails.id=Number id of the bookingdetails

Type.id= Number, id of the type
Type.share=Array with bookingdetails id.
```

This will take up a bit more space but it will be a bit faster to make lookups.
And it will make the requested operations simpler.

PS: If you use Typescript it will be even easier ;-)